# Verificar se um registro foi deletado ao executar query DELETE

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um código simples em PHP para deletar email de banco de dados, só que preciso usar um `if` e `else` se determinada ação ocorre.

Se por exemplo, apagar um email apresentar uma determinada mensagem, ou se for o caso de não ter esse email solicitado no banco de dados, aparece uma mensagem de que tal dado já não esta presente na tabela segue o código.

```
<?php 

$emailDel = $_POST['delemail'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xavier', 'xavier', 'store_database')or die('não foi possivel acessar Banco de Dados');

$query = "DELETE FROM clients WHERE email = '$emailDel'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('não foi possivel acessar Banco de Dados');



if($result = TRUE){
    echo $emailDel.' as deleting from database';
}else{
    echo $emailDel.' it is not present in database';
}

mysqli_close($dbc);


?>
```

Comment: Faltou o fetch_assoc, sem ele vc n pega o resultado da consulta

Comment: Isto esta errado `if($result = TRUE){` o certo é `if($result == TRUE){` ou `if($result === TRUE){` ou apenas `if($result){`.

Comment: @rray acho que isto não é necessário pois não é uma consulta e sim um `DELETE from`?

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: eu achei o problema bastante claro.. não entendi porque votaram negativo ou para fechar.

Comment: @rray porque as consultas do tipo `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` retornam `TRUE` ou `FALSE` apenas.

Comment: @Edilson, não tinha código antes na pergunta, imaginei que estava fazendo um select antes do delete.

Comment: @rray Sim, vi agora que a pergunta foi editada.

Answer (score 3):

Um igual `=` operador de atribuição, significa que a variável vai receber determinado valor.

Dois iguais `==` operador de condição.

Então o correto é:

```
if($result == True){
    echo $emailDel.' as deleting from database';
} else {
    echo $emailDel.' it is not present in database';
}
```

Comment: pois é, eu vi isso aqui e como estou novato no php, agora que vi a questão de == para condição tbm se estende a ele, porem esse mesmo tbm n funcionou, será que obter uma resposta de identificar se tem o valor na tabela para que o php confirme não seria possível ?

Comment: Deve ser um erro antes dessa condição, exprerimente colocar isso no início do seu arquivo PHP e edite o seu código com o erro que retornou: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` e logo abaixo
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: obrigado, mas eu tentei aqui, porem nada foi identificado.

Comment: Tem o codigo na pergunta, editei ela, não sei se foi aprovada

Comment: eu aprovei, o código esta lá sim.

Comment: `$result` recebe o retorno de `mysqli_query()`, o que não quer dizer que foi mesmo excluído algum registro pois `mysqli_query()` retorna true ou false... se for true, indica que a query foi executada sem erro esperado, mesmo que não tenha excluído nada.

Answer (score 3):

Logo após executar a query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('não foi possivel acessar Banco de Dados');
```

Verifique quantas colunas foram afetadas com a função `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

A função `mysqli_query()` retorna valor booleano.

**1.** *true*: quando a execução foi bem sucedida

**2.** *false*: quando houve algum erro.

Um detalhe importante é que quando retorna `true`, não significa que algum registro foi excluído, mas sim que a query foi executada sem problemas.

Portanto, logo após verificar o retorno da execução da query, verifique o retorno de `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

```
if ($result == true){
    if ($total = mysqli_affected_rows($dbc))
        echo 'excluído: '.$total;
    else
        echo 'Nenhum registro excluído';
else
   echo 'Houve erro na execuão da query SQL: '.mysqli_error($dbc);
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenta Assim
**$success = mysql_affected_rows();**

```
if( isset($_POST['delemail']) ){   // Se existir o post prossiga... 
$emailDel = $_POST['delemail'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xavier', 'xavier', 'store_database')or    
die('não foi possivel acessar Banco de Dados');

$query = "DELETE FROM clients WHERE email = '$emailDel'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)or die('não foi possivel acessar Banco   
de Dados');
$success = mysql_affected_rows();


if($success <> 0 ){ 
echo $emailDel.' as deleting from database';
}else{
echo $emailDel.' it is not present in database';
}

}else{    
echo"Erro";
}

mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: `<> 0` é diferente de  `!= 0`.

Comment: Isso foi uma pergunta?

Comment: Uma afirmação... pois uma pergunta possui interrogação.. srsr ... Apenas um aviso sobre o que usou na condicional.. Está errado, apesar de não gerar erro algum. Apenas semanticamente incorreto..